# Why is clearfix done the way that its done?

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-float

With clearfix you're using generated css content to create a div after all its floated siblings, so its parent doesn't collapse. My question is why use generated content? I've noticed that simply declaring a parent as display table keeps it from collapsing. Thats less code,so ehy not simply do that? Also conventionally why is display tabled used when with generated content, display block works also. Lasty I commonly see generated content after and before the floated elements, why both, isnt the last element only necessary to clear? To reiterate 1) why not simply use display:table; 2) why not display block with generated content. 3) why generated content before and after?

```
 .parent{
     display: table;//is there a reason not to do this?
  }
  .parent:after{
      content: "";
      display: block;//interchangeable with table?
      clear:both;
   }
   .parent:after,.parent:before{ //why is this beneficial?
         content: "";
         display: table;
    }
    .parent:before{
         clear: both;
    }
 <div class="parent">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: 1) You may not want to make `.parent` `display: table`. What if you just want it to be a block element? Or flex? Or inline-block? etc. #2 and #3 are covered here  http://cssmojo.com/the-very-latest-clearfix-reloaded/

Comment: ok cool ty, I read that but I'm still slightly confused, it said :before is used to keep the margins from collapsing, but only top and bottom margins collapse and if you're floating something only the left and right are effecting other floated items right? Is that to keep margins from collapsing from parent margins? Also I keep reading that display table is used to keep margins from collapsing but it seem to have the same margin rules as block, https://jsfiddle.net/o5rdznjL/42/,.  I think I'm not understanding a small aspect needed to fully understand this as a whole.